# How to implement form area box in meteors JS?

Tags: meteor

I am new for MeteorJs. Some one could you please provide info for form area text tag.I tried to add text area and tried to implement using with event.

Comment: Could you post some of your sample code that you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer from refer few docs.. below is the correct one

html:

JS:
`Template.body.events({
    "submit .new-task": function (event) {
      // Prevent default browser form submit
      event.preventDefault();
     var message=event.target.newMessage.value;`